# String variable value as a property in a type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

i try to create a type which has a variable value as a property

For example:

```
const myProp: string = 'my prop';
type Foo ={ 
    [myProp]: string
};
```

i expected that i can do:

```
const test: Foo = {
   [myProp] = myProp
}
```

But get error of:

> [ts] A computed property name in a type literal must directly refer to
>   a built-in symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to declare a type that has the same property name as a string constant you could use the following syntax (lookup type syntax)

```
const myProp = 'my prop';
type Foo = {
    [P in typeof myProp]: string
};
const test: Foo = {
    [myProp]: myProp
}
```

If you want to have several of these keys you can use a union type :

```
const myProp = 'my prop';
const otherProp = "otherProp"
type Foo = {
    [P in (typeof myProp | typeof otherProp)]: string
};
const test: Foo = {
    [myProp]: myProp,
    [otherProp]: otherProp
}
```

The typescript default libraries, actually provides a type that is equivalent to the above lookup type declaration, named `Record`. Using this you could write your type as:

```
type Foo2 = Record<typeof myProp, string>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answare :)

Answer (score 1):

You will able to do this once next version of Typescript released.

This [feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15473) already available in typescript@next. If you want to, you can install it with:
`npm install typescript@next --save-dev`

Meanwhile you can use method provided by @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir

Comment: Thanks for your answare. Maybe this will be my solution in the next time, but currently the answer of @Titan saved my day